# Is it possible to infer the keys of a Record in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am using [JSS](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss) and want to define a `style` object with both strongly typed keys and values, without defining the keys twice.

**First attempt:**

```
const style: Record<string, CSSProperties> = {
  root: {
    background: 'red'
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  ...
}
```

Now `style` is not strongly typed, so the compiler gives no warning when accessing `style.nonExistingKey`.

**Second attempt:**

If I specify the keys explicitly like this:

```
const style: Record<'root' | 'title' | ... , CSSProperties> = {
  root: {
    background: 'red'
  },
  ...
}
```

then I get a strongly typed Record, i.e. `style.nonExistingKey` will throw an error. However, this method requires duplicating the record keys as they must be explicitly added as a generic argument.

**Third attempt:**

I can create a strongly typed Record after the fact with the following code:

```
const styleObj = {
  root: {
    background: 'red'
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  ...
}

const style = styleObj as Record<keyof typeof styleObj, CSSProperties>
```

However, then I lose type-checking for the `CSSProperties` values of the record, so this is not a good solution.

**Is there a way to do something like this:**

```
const style: Record<T, CssProperties> = {
  root: {
    background: 'red'
  },
  ...
}
```

and have `T` be automatically inferred as `'root' | 'title' | ...` etc.?

Comment: Where is `Record` coming from?

Comment: It is a built in TS type, `type Record<K extends string, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
}`

Comment: And where do the property names come from? I mean `title`, `root` and so on. Where do they come from? Are they listed somewhere? Right now you're defining a Record based on  `string` so, of course, any string is valid as a key.

Comment: I am declaring the property names as part of the `style`-object, and want to use them strongly typed aftewards.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With [TypeScript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/), I think that this can finally be achieved using the new [`satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#satisfies):

```
const style = {
  root: {
    background: 'red'
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  invalid: {
    invalidProperty: '' // Type '{ invalidProperty: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
                        // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'invalidProperty' does not exist in type 'CSSProperties'.(2322)
  }
} satisfies Record<string, CSSProperties>;

type keys = keyof typeof style;  // "root" | "title" | "invalid"

style.nonExistingKey; // Property 'nonExistingKey' does not exist on type '{ ... }'.(2339)

style.root.fontWeight; // Property 'fontWeight' does not exist on type '{ background: string; }'.(2339)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgynACgJwPaWcAlhAzlAXigG8AoKCqAIwEMBjAawHM0BXAOwBMB%20ALilzBkWdkwDc5SgDNU7YAHUIWJgAtgfAUJHjSAX1Kk6swZpAAbaETIU0qYP2uVajFqg6d%20AcmQROnyboANJLYwBYOkhQycorKal5UqGZ%20AcEUIgBuNGZYHiSRUJnZuSjoEJggXp5QAPQ1UAAq4NCexIXsWTmcpRig-ILComJQutVY%20Ox2UDS4uMrsNFQWUMCoK81QnvBIaL04uJ4AdAWUp2e19QDyVABWEHTAUDnA5dlQALY0IFCyZt%204kDoWCk3wYkwA7uwoGBduVsHhAtMuJsil0enCQNVOKg8FBJo8IAAPcaPETrSCbbbozD7I4ACgATABmBkMgCUAT0Aho2FwUn2UAASvdUMhOAAeAbaRFU2E0vAAPgkpFAFIYEBA%20CI6pAqCk5IgetMFmGFygACJbMBzVAAD4W0IWc0GQTmCCHSbsACixME2gA0hrhnUoNTQJtPT6SQGNVicRMpkSST8oaqWm1DpmRvTmUyAJwc0iuiyHK2HaIKJSqYDB%20ph76eCuxatx3H4qBJkyyA2bNrOZhsLj9LRDbOHRlM-NsoA)

As shown in the examples above, this retains strong typing of all keys and values in the object, and prevents adding properties that don't satisfy the typing.

Answer (score 21):

You can use a helper function when defining the object. The function will have a type parameters that mandates all properties must be of type `CSSProperties` using an index signature. Since the function is generic the result will be typed correctly (it will not actually have an index signature but rather just the defined properties)

```
function createStyleMap<T extends { [name: string]: CSSProperties }>(cfg: T)  {
  return cfg;
}
const style = createStyleMap({
  root: {
  background: 'red'
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});

style.root //ok
style['hu'] // error
```

You can also type it to return `Record` but I don't think this would add any value

```
function createStyleMap<T extends { [name: string]: CSSProperties }>(cfg: T) : Record<keyof T, CSSProperties> {
  return cfg;
}
```

Comment: Using `Record<...>` as a return type as shown in the 2nd option is actually useful if you want to do something like this: `type Props = {  classes: Record<keyof typeof styles, string>;  };`

Comment: How can I make `CSSProperties`  generic ?

Comment: @noririco really depends on what you are trying to do ..

Comment: I Think this is a big problem of TS. There's no simple way to declare a typed map without losing the keys. This solution might work for some cases, but since T extends CSSProperties (it's not exactly CSSProperties), it will allow unknown keys, e.g, if `{ foo: 'bar' }` is passed, it will be accepted, even though 'foo' is not a key of CSSProperties. This problem can be fixed by using a function like this: `const createCssMap = <K extends string>(map: Record<K, CSSProperties>) => map`, which can be used like this: `createCssMap({ /* styles */ })`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: @noririco you can do it with an intermediate function with a generic value type: `const Homogeneous = <V>() => <T extends Record<string, V>>(ob: T) => ob` — which you would use like this: `const style = Homogeneous<CSSProperties>()({/* styles */})`.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

After learning TypeScript more, I managed to get this working in one function.
So here is new, short and working solution.

### Helper functions:

```
import { StyleRulesCallback, Theme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { CSSProperties } from 'react';

export const createStyleMap =
    <T extends keyof any>(callback: (theme: Theme) => Record<T, CSSProperties>):
    StyleRulesCallback<T extends string ? T : never> => callback;
```

### Example of component:

```
import { withStyles, WithStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import React from 'react';
import { createStyleMap } from '../utils/utils';

interface OwnProps {
    dummyName: string;
}

const styles = createStyleMap(theme =>
    ({
        content: {
            height: '100%',
            padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
            overflowY: 'auto',
            boxSizing: 'border-box'
        },
        tableHead: {
            height: 56
        }
    })
);

type Props = OwnProps 
    & WithStyles<keyof ReturnType<typeof styles>>;

class DummyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return <div className={this.props.classes.content}/>;
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(DummyComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

`[x in keyof y]` will do the trick here:

```
const styleObj = {
    root: {
      background: 'red'
    },
    title: {
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
  }
type StyleObj = {
    [P in keyof typeof styleObj]?: CSSProperties
}
const newStyleObj:StyleObj = {
    root:{
        ...
    }
}
```

Remove the `?` to make all the fields mandatory.