# How to make Typescript infer the keys of an object but define type of its value?

Tags: typescript

I want to define the type of an object but let typescript infer the keys and don't have as much overhead to make and maintain a UnionType of all keys.

Typing an object will allow all strings as keys:

```
const elementsTyped: { 
    [key: string]: { nodes: number, symmetric?: boolean }
} = {
    square: { nodes: 4, symmetric: true },
    triangle: { nodes: 3 }
}

function isSymmetric(elementType: keyof typeof elementsTyped): boolean {
    return elementsTyped[elementType].symmetric;
}
isSymmetric('asdf'); // works but shouldn't
```

Inferring the whole object will show an error and allows all kind of values:

```
const elementsInferred = {
    square: { nodes: 4, symmetric: true },
    triangle: { nodes: 3 },
    line: { nodes: 2, notSymmetric: false /* don't want that to be possible */ }
}

function isSymmetric(elementType: keyof typeof elementsInferred): boolean {
    return elementsInferred[elementType].symmetric; 
    // Property 'symmetric' does not exist on type '{ nodes: number; }'.
}
```

The closest I got was this, but it don't want to maintain the set of keys like that:

```
type ElementTypes = 'square' | 'triangle'; // don't want to maintain that :(
const elementsTyped: { 
    [key in ElementTypes]: { nodes: number, symmetric?: boolean }
} = {
    square: { nodes: 4, symmetric: true },
    triangle: { nodes: 3 },
    lines: { nodes: 2, notSymmetric: false } // 'lines' does not exist in type ...
    // if I add lines to the ElementTypes as expected => 'notSymmetric' does not exist in type { nodes: number, symmetric?: boolean }
}

function isSymmetric(elementType: keyof typeof elementsTyped): boolean {
    return elementsTyped[elementType].symmetric;
}
isSymmetric('asdf'); // Error: Argument of type '"asdf"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"square" | "triangle"'.
```

Is there a better way to define the object without maintaining the set of keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to infer the keys of a Record in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538199/is-it-possible-to-infer-the-keys-of-a-record-in-typescript)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

So you want something that infers keys but restricts the value types and uses [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) to disallow extra properties.  I think the easiest way to get that behavior is to introduce a helper function:

```
// Let's give a name to this type
interface ElementType {
  nodes: number,
  symmetric?: boolean
}

// helper function which infers keys and restricts values to ElementType
const asElementTypes = <T>(et: { [K in keyof T]: ElementType }) => et;
```

This helper function [infers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) the type `T` from the mapped type of `et`.  Now you can use it like this:

```
const elementsTyped = asElementTypes({
  square: { nodes: 4, symmetric: true },
  triangle: { nodes: 3 },
  line: { nodes: 2, notSymmetric: false /* error where you want it */} 
});
```

The type of the resulting `elementsTyped` will (once you fix the error) have inferred keys `square`, `triangle`, and `line`, with values `ElementType`.

Hope that works for you.  Good luck!

Comment: ok I feared that it might need an helper. would be amazing if typescript could do that without it. 
also I can use that only for this usecase. is there a way to make the `ElementType` generic too? I wasn't able to without breaking the key inference or excess property checking (thanks for the keyword ;) )

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "make the `ElementType` generic" without a concrete example.  And if the new question is significantly different from the question as asked you might want to post a new one.

Comment: well would be nice if I could use that there was a generic `asTypedObject<MyValueType>(...)` function. here: `asElementTypes= asTypedObject<ElementType>`.

Comment: In the absence of [partial type parameter inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) you can use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to achieve this: `const asTypedObject = <E>() => <T>(et: { [K in keyof T]: E }) => et;   const asElementType = asTypedObject<ElementType>();`

Comment: thanks although unfortunately that function works without the addional type and then obviously doesn't have the excess property checking. `const asElementType = asTypedObject(); // forgot <ElementType>`. well I don't think I need that `asTypedObject` but was interested in if thats possible.

Comment: It might be possible to get closer to what you’re looking for but the comment section of an already-answered question probably isn’t a great forum for it.  If you’re really interested in getting an answer to this it might be worth making a new question so you get more eyes on it... after you search, of course, since “how to require a type parameter” might be answered elsewhere.

Comment: @Jack: function asElementTypes<T>() {
    return function <Obj>(obj: { [K in keyof Obj]: T }) {
        return obj;
    };
}

Comment: @tokland anyway to use that function without the double invocation asProvidedType<MyProvidedType>()({a:"a"})

Answer (score 13):

### TypeScript >=4.9.0

TypeScript `4.9.0` adds the [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#satisfies) keyword which can be used to constrain the values of an object while inferring the keys.

```js
type ElementValue = {
  nodes: number;
  symmetric?: boolean;
};

const elements = {
  square: { nodes: 4, symmetric: true },
  triangle: { nodes: 3 },
} satisfies Record<string, ElementValue>;

type Elements = typeof elements;
type ElementType = keyof Elements;

function isSymmetric(elementType: ElementType): boolean {
  const element = elements[elementType];
  return 'symmetric' in element && element.symmetric;
}

isSymmetric('asdf'); // doesn't work
```

### TypeScript <4.9.0

An intermediate function can be used to constrain the values of an object while inferring the keys.

```js
type ElementValue = {
  nodes: number;
  symmetric?: boolean;
};

function typedElements<T extends Record<string, ElementValue>>(o: T) {
  return o;
}

const elements = typedElements({
  square: { nodes: 4, symmetric: true },
  triangle: { nodes: 3 },
});

type Elements = typeof elements;
type ElementType = keyof Elements;

function isSymmetric(elementType: ElementType): boolean {
  const element = elements[elementType];
  return 'symmetric' in element && element.symmetric;
}

isSymmetric('asdf'); // doesn't work
```

Comment: Use `satisfies` should be the new accepted answer. Easiest and needs no helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Another, simpler solution involves the use of `enum` instead of complex TS type inheritance:

```
type SiteRoute = {
  title: string
  path: string
  isAdmin?: boolean
  disabled?: boolean
}

enum Routes {
    home = "home",
    events = "events",
    contacts = "contacts",
}

const ROUTES_DETAILS: Record<Routes, SiteRoute> = {
    [Routes.home]: {
        title: "Home",
        path: "/",
    },
    [Routes.events]: {
        title: "Events",
        path: "/events",
        disabled: true,

    },
    [Routes.contacts]: {
        title: "Contacts",
        path: "/contacts",
        isAdmin: true,
        disabled: true,
    },
}

ROUTES_DETAILS.home  // ok with autocomplete
ROUTES_DETAILS.asa   // Error: Property 'asa' does not exist on type
```

This solution is more readable and uses basic types and `enum`. The only drawback is that `enum` should be paired with a **string value** in order to be human-readable in autocompletion.