# How can I use programmatic object keys as TypeScript type?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following object:

```js
const obj = {
  foo: "bar",
  hello: "world",
}
```

and the following object processing function:

```js
const process = (obj) => {
  const processedObj = {}
  for (const key in obj) {
    processedObj[`--${key}`] = obj[key]
  }
  return processedObj
}
```

How can I type `key` argument to only accept processed keys that start with `--`?

```js
const processedObj = process(obj)
const getValue = (key) => {
  return processedObj[key]
}
```

Trying to programatically convert JS object properties to CSS variables so that Visual Studio Code IntelliSense feature suggests `getValue("--foo")` when typing `getValue("--f")`.

Comment: You want things that are keys of the type of the object, so... `keyof typeof obj`?

Comment: Now it looks like you want https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html. But _are_ you using TypeScript? Nothing you've shown actually has any type information - maybe that would be a good starting point?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am using TypeScript… used plain JS to show use case with as little code as possible.

Comment: But as you've already seen with the answer below, not giving enough context means you get answers that don't actually address your problem. If you're asking about TS behaviour, _types_ seem like a pretty obvious thing to include. And _show_ your research; you could have included the linked question when asking so you didn't get told something you already knew.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Trying my best here… sorry for not making question clear enough. I updated question as quickly as I could when it appeared misleading.

Comment: There's more or less exactly what you're looking for in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `keyof typeof`:

```
const func = (key : keyof typeof obj) => {
  return obj[key]
}
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGAzEIAXDAETwCGATiQDTYwA2IlApgLbEkCWADhAK5tamAL4BuTJlCRYufmGCoYACgDWLAJ4xi6jSFwwoGni31wkASlQA+DPVZR+lMOcQBtXQF1RQA)

Comment: Thanks for helping out… what if obj is generated programatically?

Comment: Can you write an explanatory example?

Comment: On it… will update question.

Comment: See updated question… question needed more context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312165/using-the-keys-of-an-object-literal-as-a-typescript-type answers original question.