# Typescript error：Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Opts {
  onFrame: () => void;
  onAudioSample: null;
  emulateSound: boolean;
  sampleRate: number;
}

class NES {
    constructor(opts: Opts) {
        this.opts = {
            onFrame() { },
            onAudioSample: null,
            emulateSound: true,
            sampleRate: 44100,
        }

        if (typeof opts !== "undefined") {
            let key: keyof Opts
            for (key in this.opts) {
                if (typeof opts[key] !== "undefined") {
                    // got err here
                    this.opts[key] = opts[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    opts: Opts
}
```

you can cheak the error on TS playground：[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=2&ssl=27&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAcwGdkG8BQyyA9iAGJRwC2EAXMgBQCUyAvAHzIBuxwAJgG5CJEAEEArn2DEAytXQAbOshDiFCoUQhU1cSDOLiQfegCNixJXBCbkWeUoBKe5aqqnoQgL758CBXBYOAByAKIyeMJECKRYYFDiCGDEUAzEmFj0GNgsBET5+WAAFsBYAHTp2GyRBbX5pBTUEMx4yF4ANFF19WKS0nJUiq5qCp3dtdq6+obG9PHiEGPj+faDTi70ACybAIwADHtLdT5dBcAwjGAAnugQxBeVOACErKzIAERGfBAwoBB871yp26SjAyAA1hArvRIVd7mgMsC6jAUoxYchQMhiqUKhkgctuudLjc7g8MgBtWEAXWQLzen2MPz+APxBOW2PKj0pUJpby51NsbPyPiFIu6YqIEpIGSyiK8QA)

typescript: v3.8.3
`err: Type 'number'` is not assignable to type `never`. 
I don't understand why it is a `never` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because TypeScript can't infer that `this.opts[key]` and `opts[key]` are the same type. If you were to cover up each half of the `=`:

- `opts[key]` could be a `Function`, `null`, `boolean`, or `number`
- `this.opts[key]` needs to receive a `Function`, `null`, `boolean`, or `number`
  depending on the value of `key`, which we don't know
- the only supertype in common for `Function`, `null`, `boolean`, and `number` is `never`,
  so that's the type that TypeScript wants for `this.opts[key]`

Interestingly, if you were to extract this to an anonymous generic function, it works: Within a single assignment Typescript *can* infer and use the type `Opts[K]`. [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) suggests a similar solution in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54598743/1426891).

```js
if (typeof opts[key] !== "undefined") {
  // this.opts[key] = opts[key];
  (<K extends keyof Opts>(k: K) => { this.opts[k] = opts[k]; })(key);
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=2&ssl=22&ssc=88&pln=22&pc=21#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)

That said, I would use the spread operator as in [Mukesh Soni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61672028/1426891), ending your assignment of `this.opts` with `...opts`, or use `Object.assign`. There's a slight risk that the passed `opts` contains extra keys, but Typescript should ensure otherwise at compile time. (For that matter, if you're expecting `opts` to be optional and potentially incomplete, it should probably be defined as `opts?: Partial<Opts>`.)

```js
class NES {
    constructor(opts?: Partial<Opts>) {
        this.opts = Object.assign({
            onFrame() { },
            onAudioSample: null,
            emulateSound: true,
            sampleRate: 44100,
        }, opts);
    }
    opts: Opts
}
```

**See also:** [Object spread vs. Object.assign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32925460/1426891), which notes that the solutions are quite similar and both applicable for default options values.

Comment: thank you, your solution is good, I use type assert solved it, seems your solution is better.

Comment: my solution:   (this.opts[key] as Opts[typeof key]) = opts[key]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are getting that error. One other way to merge both the options might be to use spread operators.

```
this.opts = {
            onFrame() { },
            onAudioSample: null,
            emulateSound: true,
            sampleRate: 44100,
            ...opts
        };
```

Comment: If they do it this way, then casting with 'as Opts' is unnecessary, right?

Comment: True in this case since the instance variable has been typed outside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `as any` after the property access, TypeScript will check that `key` is a valid key

```
if (typeof opts[key] !== "undefined") {
  (this.opts[key] as any) = opts[key];
}
```