# Typescript type safe update of property by string property name

Tags: typescript, keyof, typescript3.8

I'm needing to update the value of a property of a class by a string property name. I started off by making sure the property name was valid via this method:

```js
export class ClientDTO {
    ...

    static isValidPropertyName(name: string): name is keyof ClientDTO {
        return (name as keyof ClientDTO) !== undefined
    }
}
```

And then in another class I'm doing this:

```js
foo(key: string, newValue: string) {
  if (!ClientDTO.isValidPropertyName(key)) {
    return
  }

  if (newValue !== this.originalClient[key]) {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.originalClient[key] = newValue
  }
}
```

The lookup works well now, but to do the update I'm having to put the `// @ts-ignore` there and I'd really like to figure out how to do this properly without having to have the ignore there.

I have strict checkings turned on so I get the error

> TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: What error do you get when the `//@ts-ignore` is removed?

Comment: TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: Are you sure `name as keyof ClientDTO` is validating anything at runtime? Does `ClientDTO` have any non-`string` properties?

Comment: I am assuming that that `this.originalClient` is an instance of `ClientDTO`, right? If so, are all of the instance properties on it of type `string`? Or is there a mix of types?

Comment: Yes it’s a ClientDTO. It’s a mix of types. String, Boolean, date and number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
return (name as keyof ClientDTO) !== undefined
```

This doesn't check that `name` is a key of ClientDTO. It asserts that it is, and then checks whether the string is undefined. Try it in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vWAewDsIAXAJwFdhi9SAKAB3ICMQBLYaMALmhNNYIBzADTRGLdtCY8C5ALZMApqQCU6aAF8MWjADNyBKq0LRWEBMkgQACqTz1lxeAzsPSTgHJg5innwGCKjz0ro7wXj6mMADWivB4unBIKDCYONCkisTkpATQLvZhEYqcMXEJSZZQagCEALx10AYAJoq6AorNANzaGBj4RHggigB0IHiCtGYWKbaF7s4ARMCLKipd0AD0m2L8BMQwi2TkiotAA).

Even if that worked, it would only check that the string is a valid key of ClientDTO, but does not say which one it is. Therefore, Typescript checks that the type you're setting is safely assignable to *any* key of ClientDTO; since ClientDTO contains "a mix of types" including "String, Boolean, date and number", the only safe value to assign is `never`.

For you to safely assign a `newValue: string`, you'll need a function that ensures at runtime that your `key` is for a `string`-typed property, which might involve some duplication.

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(
        public a: string,
        public b: string,
        public c: string,
        public x: number,
        public y: number,
        public z: number) { }
}

function isStringProperty(propertyName: string): propertyName is "a" | "b" | "c" {
    return ["a", "b", "c"].indexOf(propertyName) >= 0;
}

function isNumberProperty(propertyName: string): propertyName is "x" | "y" | "z" {
    return ["x", "y", "z"].indexOf(propertyName) >= 0;
}

function setString(dto: MyClass, key: string, newValue: string) {
    if (isStringProperty(key)) {
        dto[key] = newValue;
    }
}

function setNumber(dto: MyClass, key: string, newValue: number) {
    if (isNumberProperty(key)) {
        dto[key] = newValue;
    }
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vWAewDsIAXAJwFdhi9SAKLHRgB3ICMQBLYaMALmhKkOBAOYAaBo2wt2XaK36Dh4yVJmduwRWWUSpOdXIAe-AuQC2rAKak9+6Ie7xTF67dXM2G6AC8XlmwBKdGgAXwxwjAAzcgIqDkJoDggAZR1RAAVSPCYbYnhaJmzc0nyAOTBzK20hUUD+Ipy8+AqqpJgAIjAO6AAfaA7WHv6O4B7MRlIrYnJSAmgAbS6OsQGh1dGOgF0AOmEAEysjAHkowuLm1qtggD4AXmgABgBuCIxo2PjE5LLXGyymqUCo0SuVKtUBOkRPUHBcgVd2gMjMMBvAUR0fONVFMZnNFh1kRs0RtMbsDkdTudAWCqrcHi83h84sQEvMINM0rURLR9tR+AhkJAIKsANZWZyQrmrAhWADuADUwCByBClHV0KoOFFoLRkpzlADQQUxfBAsEJvZeXgFiattAHjKFUqVa9GOFIjFmayBNNfgE6Fb+UgUMLoCaarpoI7FcqIWZ-ebNdrdRA-W5Dc1aCazRr7NArTbxXaHXKYy7VO6gA)

See also: [Typescript error：Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61671898/1426891)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about typescriptlang.org/play, that's so awesome!

Comment: BTW: `["x", "y", "z"].includes(propertyName)` is slightly more compact (elegant?) and available and [available since many years](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#browser_compatibility)

Comment: @MarcelWaldvogel And it is completely not supported in Internet Explorer, for which Microsoft only retired support last month. I'm afraid it not practical for me to rephrase the answer in every combination of compatibility and elegance, and I'm sorry my default now and in May 2020 did not match your current opinion.

Comment: This wasn't meant to show your ignorance or to point out the age of yesteryear's code, quite the opposite. SO is used by many novice programmers to build their skills and style or adapt best practices. The comment was meant for them.
(As TS is transpiled anyway, I prefer to use new language constructs and APIs whenever useful, and use things like `es6-shim` to polyfill API differences. But these are personal opinions and/or business decisions.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your custom type guard:

```
isValidPropertyName(name: string): name is keyof ClientDTO { ... }
```

is guarding against any key of `ClientDTO`, so when you try to use it:

```
this.originalClient[key] = newValue // newValue is type string
```

TypeScript is tries to infer the right type for the value of `this.originalClient[key]`. Since `key` could be *any* key of `ClientDTO`, the value you assign to it must be assignable to all of the value types of those keys. Since you have a mix of value types for those keys, the only type which is assignable to all of them is the bottom type `never`; a type to which nothing can be assigned, hence the error.

To fix this, note that you give `newValue` type `string`. So restrict your type guard to only those keys of `ClientDTO` who's values are strings:

```
type KeysWithStringValues<T extends {}> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

class ClientDTO {
    /* ... */
    static isValidPropertyName(name: string): name is KeysWithStringValues<ClientDTO> {
        // Make sure to replace this with code that ACTUALLY enforces
        // the above constraint.
        return name !== undefined
    }
}
```

---

[Playground Link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBA0lMBnA6gSxACwMogE5oB2A5gGoCGANgK5RIA8AKjFAB4hSEAmSMA3gF8AfDAC8-YDCkwA2nBhEYAa0QB7AGYxGAXQBcWudpbtOPGEnxFiMAPzwY+wlABuUPAG5gAmSrAat2p7AbBCqeCAwAMaU5Ei8AMKUaJwgACKMAPIS0uaqALZQCGAAhPoWBCSeOUj5UBlYbkWlMITUeQBGbkHVIOQgaJEKSBRJXAAKeKrQ4WAAcuQFABSEC1BlliQAlI6rQ-CIqBg4G2RUtAyJyYRpmSJ8kjnSeFAg1HiEMMu7scpqmpcpdIZTYwYqicTUbhQdREKBcB5SAReYDAaKxXgAMVUqmy0jCaGIRCoAOuzRJNwyVWkCJg6mxi186wqxAANC0oAB3Ea0JlWEH3R7SNCaRbFclAgB0aGGVDQ40m03A8yWvk2-Jpgqkz1e7w10iReqkws+Ti5Z1gYPEWGlEvxhJWlHJPkQ2nVmse1qQtoI9uJSRSzrARnEpu5UENMCROSRAiAA)

Comment: This is cool but seems not not work well when you start throwing in optional types.