# Assigning type to object values in Typescript with narrowing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

I'm trying to dynamically create a settings menu in TS based on this data:

```
const userSettings = {
    testToggle: {
        title: "Toggle me",
        type: "toggle",
        value: false,
    },
    testDropdown: {
        title: "Test Dropdown",
        type: "dropdown",
        value: "Change me",
        selectValues: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
    },
    testText: {
        title: "Test textbox",
        type: "text",
        value: "Change me",
}
```

This allows me to access each user input field easily using

```
userSettings.testToggle.value
```

I am struggling to do the typing for the userSettings object. So far I have come up with

```
export type InputFieldTypes = {
    toggle: boolean,
    text: string,
    dropdown: string,
}

type ExtraProperties = Merge<{ [_ in keyof InputFieldTypes]: {} }, {
    // Additional properties which will be added to the input field with the same key
    dropdown: {
        selectValues: string[],
    },
}>

type FieldOptions<K, V extends Partial<Record<keyof K, any>>> = {
    [P in keyof K]: {
        title: string,
        type: P,
        value: K[P],
    } & V[P]
}[keyof K]

export type InputField = FieldOptions<InputFieldTypes, ExtraProperties>;
```

which generates a nice union:

```
type InputField = {
 title: string;
 type: "toggle";
 value: boolean; } | {
 title: string;
 type: "text";
 value: string; } | ({
 title: string;
 type: "dropdown";
 value: string; } & {
 selectValues: string[]; })
```

correctly restricting the toggle values to booleans and requiring the dropdown to have the selectValues property. However, assigning type `{ [key: string]: InputField }` to `userSettings` is too wide, as `userSettings.testToggle.value` has type `boolean | string`, and I would like to avoid casting.

The closest I have managed is a function

```
const asInputFieldObject = <T,>(et: { [K in keyof T]: InputField & T[K] }) => et;
const settings = asInputFieldObject(userSettings);
```

which behaves mostly as expected, enforcing both that userSettings objects are InputFields and allowing accesses like `settings.darkMode.value` to be typed correctly, but throws the rather unhelpful error

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

when attempting to assign a number to the toggle instead of a boolean. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Edit:

To clarify, the issue I have is specifically with assigning a type to `userSettings`, as I want `userSettings.testToggle.value` to be a `boolean` rather than `string | boolean` as is the case with `Record<string, InputField>` or `{ [key: string]: InputField }`, and likewise for the other inputs. It is possible to assign types to objects in this way, (see [How to make Typescript infer the keys of an object but define type of its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598322/how-to-make-typescript-infer-the-keys-of-an-object-but-define-type-of-its-value)), however simply assigning InputField does not fix the issue, as the `value` access still has the union type of all values.

`asInputFieldObject` is my latest attempt at fixing this by adding the intersect type to the mapped type: `[K in keyof T]: InputField & T[K]`. This results in a type of the form:

```
const userSettings: {
 darkMode: {
   title: string;
   type: "toggle";
   value: boolean;
 } & {
   title: string;
   type: "toggle";
   value: false;
 };
 testDropdown: {
   title: string;
   type: "dropdown";
   value: string;
 } & {
   selectValues: string[];
 } & {
 ...;
 }; }
```

which works well in most cases, but when an incorrect type is given to `value`, instead of directly complaining about the wrong type it will throw a `not assignable to type 'never'.` error due to the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a variable of `InputField` type, you can perform type narrowing so that TypeScript could determine which type is suitable for assignment.

```
var inputField: InputField;
switch (inputField.type) {
  case 'toggle':
    inputField.value; // is boolean
    inputField.value = 1; // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
    break;

  case 'text':
    inputField.value; // is string
    break;

  case 'dropdown':
    inputField.selectValues; // is string[]
    break;

  default:
}
```

EDIT: After reading the original question, you could type the `userSettings` like the following...

```
interface ToggleInputField {
  title: string;
  type: 'toggle';
  value: boolean;
}
interface DropDownInputField {
  title: string;
  type: 'dropdown';
  value: string;
  selectValues: string[];
}
interface TextInputField {
  title: string;
  type: 'text';
  value: string;
}
type InputField = ToggleInputField | DropDownInputField | TextInputField;

const userSettings: Record<string, InputField> = {
  testToggle: {
    title: 'Toggle me',
    type: 'toggle', // automatically identified to be ToggleInputField
    value: false,
  },
  testDropdown: {
    title: 'Test Dropdown',
    type: 'dropdown', // automatically identified to be DropDownInputField
    value: 'Change me',
    selectValues: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'],
  },
  testText: {
    title: 'Test textbox',
    type: 'text', // automatically identified to be TextInputField
    value: 'Change me',
  },
};
```

Naming each input field type will help whenever you hover on a field, for example, hovering on `userSettings.testDropdown.selectValues` field will show the type being `DropDownInputField.selectValues: string[]`.

Comment: I set the `type`s for each input in the `userSettings` object, so I would like to try to avoid having to explicitly narrow the type. The mapping `asInputFieldObject = <T,>(et: { [K in keyof T]: InputField & T[K] }) => et` mostly succeeds at doing this, allowing TS to correctly figure out the type of `settings.darkMode.value` as boolean, but results in unhelpful `never` errors caused by the intersection.

Comment: I guess TypeScript hasn't been very good at static analysis yet if we don't go the "straight" road (like I've presented and in the TS handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions ).

Comment: @Ivs I've added some more clarification for solving your problem of setting type for `userSettings`. Please check if the solution works for you.

Comment: Sorry, disregard the previous comment, I got a little lost in my code :) The line `export type InputField = FieldOptions<InputFieldTypes, ExtraProperties>;` in the original code is doing the same thing as your code, it create the type union programmatically to avoid repetition. The issue I have is specifically with `const userSettings: Record<string, InputField>` or `{[key: string]: InputField}`, as this means `userSettings.testDropdown.value` will be a `string | boolean`. Will add an edit to clarify this below my post.